# Seaborn Restore marker edges

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Apparently, importing seaborn sets the marker edges in a `matplotlib.pyplot.plot` to zero or deletes them.

e.g. `plt.plot(x,y,maker='s',markerfacecolor='none')`
results in a plot without markers.

Is there a way to get the edges back?

`markeredgecolor='k'` has no effect.

Comment: `markeredgewidth` or `mew`

Comment: This works with pyplot.plot(), who do you do it for pyplot.scatter() ?

Comment: `plt.scatter` has differently named keyword arguments, I think you want `linewidth`.

Answer (score 1):

Give `edgecolor='k'` a try. This worked for me in a similar scatter plot.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this is after importing seaborn do the following:

`matplotlib.rcParams['lines.markeredgewidth'] = 1`